# Add headers info from controller to httpContextAccessor

Tags: .net-core, http-headers, jwt

In my `Dot Net Core` application, I've headers information in `Request.Form` that I want to pass to `httpContextAccessor` for further token/ session validation. But I'm stuck that How can I pass this information.

Here is my controller;

```
var header = Request.Form["header"];
```

This is what I got in header;

```
function () {

    var headers = new http_1.HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.localStorage.getDataObject(constants_1.Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN) });
    return headers;
}
```

Now I'm trying to pass it like this

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("headerKey", header);
```

But it is giving me this error;

> Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x000D

Can someone guide me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: 0x000D is a carriage return. What's the value of your header your get from Request.Form["header"]? And why do you pass a header in the Response.Headers - you want to send it back to the client?

Comment: I already added response.Headers detail in Question. Actually I'm getting front end data in Request.Form that includes header information as well. And now I want to pass this headers information to httpContextAccessor for further verification.

Comment: What's the exact value of your localstorage access_token? Maybe there's a 0x000D in this value?